# rails form helper change form text_field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a **User** model that defines an `has_one :profile` association.

On the user edit action/page I update the user attributes. I would like to update an attribute that does *not* belong to the **User** model but to the **Profile** one.

This is my view :

```
# _form.html.haml
=f.text_field :phone
```

Using this form, how could I also update the `phone` attribute of `@user.profile` ?

Comment: Please clarify the relation between user and profile tables and the corresponding fields with their associations.

Comment: You need a nested form for the Profile object. See nested resources doc'

Answer (score 1):

You should allow update of nested attributes in your User model :

```
class User
    has_one :profile
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

end
```

Then in your form use the `fields_for` method to nest fields from Profile into the User form :

```
= f.fields_for :profile do |p|
  = p.text_field :phone
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general idea if you have two tables user and profile with associations then -

User table = id, first_name, last_name

Profile table = id, user_id, phone

Associations:

`User Class` -

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :profile
end
```

`Profile Class` -

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

`User Controller` -

```
def index
  @user = current_user
  @user_phone = @user.profile.phone

end
```